# Insert data into inner array in MongoDB

Tags: php, json, mongodb, database

I have a little problem, hope You can help me.
I have next array structure in MongoDB:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("4e43cf96e7c7914b87d2e0ff"),
"list" :[
    {
    "id" : ObjectId("4e43cf96e62883ee06000002"),
    "user_name" : "login",
    "comments" : [ ]  //insert here new data
    },
    {
    "id" : ObjectId("4e43cf96e62883ee06000003"),
    "user_name" : "login",
    "comments" : [ ]
    }
]
}
```

And I want to insert new data to comments by "list.id". But I try like that:

```
$post_id = "4e43cf96e62883ee06000002";
$this->connection->user->feed->update(
    array ('list.id' => new MongoId($post_id) ), 
    array ('$push' => array ('list'=>array('comments'=>$data ) ))
)
```

But that code create new field in structure, but not add data to field 'comments':

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("4e43cf96e7c7914b87d2e0ff"),
"list" :[
     {
     "id" : ObjectId("4e43cf96e62883ee06000002"),
     "user_name" : "login",
     "comments" : [ ]  //insert here new data
     },    
     {
     "id" : ObjectId("4e43cf96e62883ee06000003"),
     "user_name" : "login",
     "comments" : [ ]
     },            
     {
     "comments" : { //added new field
        //there is my data
     }
]
}
```

Also I tried:

```
$this->connection->user->feed->update(
     array ('list.id' => new MongoId($post_id) ), 
     array ('$push' => array ('list.comments'=>$data ) ) 
  );
```

But nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works fine in mongo console :)

```
db.yar.update({"list.id":ObjectId("4e43cf96e62883ee06000002")}, {"$addToSet":{"list.$.comments":"my cool comment"}});
```

Comment: yea, You're right;) thank You a lot!! And can You tell me please what does char "$" means in "list.$.comments"? Or give me a reference? Thanks!

Comment: [Link to doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator)

Answer (score 1):

Use $addToSet modifier, because comments is a array not field.

Comment: I change '$push' to '$addToSet', but that code has same behavior as with '$push' (add new field, I show example in question)

Comment: and also I use '$push' to add data to 'list' array, and it works with '$push'.